# Magento 1.9.2 coupon( discount) not appearing while creating invoice

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales-order, invoice, create-invoice

We are currently using magento 1.9.2 and facing some issue, discount is not showing on invoice. Neither on invoice pdf nor on invoice page. This issue only appear if order is created from magento admin and if order is created from frontend then invoice shows discount price( coupon code also) and also shows us in pdf.

This issue happens only in invoice because we can easily see the discount coupon on order created page.I have also attach the screen shot.

Thanks
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you create order from back-end it doesn't show the discount / coupon code option. for this you need some extension.

You can check extension on the link below :

https://community.magento.com/t5/Admin-Configuration-Questions/Coupon-codes-for-orders-placed-in-the-backend-admin/td-p/9009